# rsync has been interrupted - copy from beginning

Tags: rsync

I was using rsync to copy files from one pc tp another.
And the 'remote' pc stopped working , so I had to restart.

Now , how can I use rsync in order not to copy all the files again from the beginning.

If I use `--ignore-existing`  ?

Note ,that one file for example which was 10MB , maybe be copied to the remote ,but only part of it (for example 5MB) .
How can I use rsync to copy the rest of these files?

Comment: IMO better would be to use `--update` option.

Comment: @NikTh:You think this would work as I want?(make it an asnwer if yes :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the better choice would be the `--update` option in rsync.

```
rsync --help | grep update
```

> -u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver

Also the `--partial` option is useful in such cases.

> **--partial**
>
> By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more
>   desirable  to  keep  partially transferred files. Using the --partial
>   option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a
>   subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

I would use `--partial` and `--update` together.

Comment: :Ok, thanks!(and happy new year from Greece :) )

Comment: :I am using 'rsync -avzheuP  ssh --progress ... ' but it returns me " Failed to exec uP: No such file or directory (2)
".Am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: I think the P is not needed if you use `--partial` or/and `--progress`. They are the same thing. Try to omit P. See `rsync --help | grep -i progre`

Comment: :Ok, I had to do rsync -avzhe ssh --partial --update ,in order to work.Thanks!

Comment: there's also `--partial-dir`